# It is known that $L \subsetneq PH$?

Tags: oracles, polynomial-hierarchy, logspace

Is it known whether $Logspace$ is **strictly** contained in the polynomial time hierarchy ?

Are there oracles relative to which these classes are equal / distinct ?

Comment: No, this is not known. For all we know, PH may collapse to uniform $\mathrm{AC}^0[6]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is equivalent to $LOGSPACE≠NP$ (which is obviously open). The proof of that equivalence relativizes (at least under the usual oracle models).

And there are oracles making $LOGSPACE = NP$ (the PSPACE-complete TQBF works) and making them not equal (the oracle separating P from NP works).